# Automatic Scrolling with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView        cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SliderCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"articleCellslider" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *item = [_articleListslider objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

   // set the article image
    [cell.image setImageWithURL:[item objectForKey:@"image"]];

  // set the text of title UILabel
    cell.title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n", [item objectForKey:@"title"]];
    cell.title.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0f/255.0f green:74.0f/255.0f blue:146.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    // set the text of summary UILabel
    cell.description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", [item objectForKey:@"description"]];
        cell.description.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14];

    cell.targetURL = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
    cell.sliderphoto = [item objectForKey:@"sliderphoto"];
    cell.date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n", [item objectForKey:@"pubDate"]];
    cell.category.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n", [item objectForKey:@"category"]];
    return cell;

}
```

My intention is to have the items in this collection view scroll horizontally automatically.

How do I get an automatic scrolling with this setup for my collection view?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by automatic scrolling? Scroll to where? When?

Comment: @TimothyMoose I haven't tried anything as yet. I'm not too sure how to move forward. The end result I am looking to achieve is similar to a slideshow where it scrolls through the items in a round robin fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out **[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)**. It's very easy to integrate and will solve your problem.